# Problems using numpy nanmean / nanmax / nanmin along axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nan

I have a 4-D conductivity array and I need to calculate variances from it. To do that, I calculate mean, maximum and minimum values along the first (time) axis. However, all three return the same value.

I have tried using for loops but it is taking a long time.

I read input files and calculate the parameters using

```
cond = data.variables['sigma']

condmean = np.nanmean(cond[:][0][:][:], axis=0)
condmax = np.nanmax(cond[:][0][:][:], axis=0)
condmin = np.nanmin(cond[:][0][:][:], axis=0)
```

However, the outputs have the same value and, therefore, variability is zero:

```
    print('average conductivity =', condmean)

    average conductivity = [[       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [2.50776908 2.50829063 2.50866258 ... 2.50802142 2.50724329 2.5075425 ]
 ...
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]]

    print('maximum conductivity =', condmax)

    maximum conductivity = [[       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [2.50776908 2.50829063 2.50866258 ... 2.50802142 2.50724329 2.5075425 ]
 ...
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]]

    print('minimum conductivity =', condmin)

    minimum conductivity = [[       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [2.50776908 2.50829063 2.50866258 ... 2.50802142 2.50724329 2.5075425 ]
 ...
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]]

    print('variability =', condvar)

    variability = [[-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0]
 ...
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ... -- -- --]]
```

I also noticed the first array (cond[0][0][:][:]) has the same value as the other parameters, so I think the code is not calculating the mean as it should and is just taking this value:

```
cond[0] is: [[       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [2.50776908 2.50829063 2.50866258 ... 2.50802142 2.50724329 2.5075425 ]
 ...
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
 [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]]
```

Comment: FYI: Numpy allows multidimensional indexing.  I suspect that instead of `cond[:][0][:][:]`, you meant to use `cond[:, 0, :, :]`.  In fact, `cond[:][0][:][:]` probably does not do what you expect; it is equivalent to `cond[0]`.

Comment: problem solved! thank you :)